# Should Spark transformation be broken to functions

Tags: apache-spark

It looks like all the Spark examples found in web are built in as single long function (usually in main)

But it is often the case that it makes sense to break the long call into functions like:

1. Improve readability
2. Share code between solution paths

A typical signature would look like this (this is Java code but similar signature would appear in all languages)

```
private static Dataset<Row> myFiltering(Dataset<Row> data) {
    return data.filter(functions.col("firstName").isNotNull()).filter(functions.col("lastName").isNotNull());
}
```

The problem here is that there is no safety for the content of the `Row`, as there is no enforcement on the fields, and calling the function becomes not only a matter of matching the singnature but also the content of `Row`.  Which obviously may (and does in my case) cause errors.

What is the best practice you enforce in large scale development environments? do you leave the code as one long function? do you suffer every time you change field names?

Comment: I suggest to mark question as "Community Wiki", because it's Off Topic now, like other "best solution" question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should split your method into smaller methods. Be aware, that many small functions also are not much readable ;)

My rules:

1. Split some chain of transformation if we can name it - if we have name, it means that this is some kind of subfunction
2. If there are many functions of the same domain - extract new class or even package.
3. KISS: don't split if your function call chain is short and also describes some subfunction, even if some lines may be extracted - it is not as much readable to read many many custom functions
4. Any larger - not in 1-3 lines - filters, maps I suggest to extract to method and use method reference

Marked as Community Wiki, because this is only my point of view and it's OT for StackOverflow. It someone else has any other suggestions, please share it :)

Comment: thx for the reply, I agree community wiki is more appropriate so thx for changing it. one question, how do you handle the field names? how do you manage and keep track of them?

Comment: @Anton.P To be honest, I keep them inlined, sometimes extract to contant will be ok - but for 50 fields and many temporary fields it's hard to manage a list of contant